# How the current users of an ios and android app affected after releasing a new version which requires higher min SDK than the one they use?

Tags: android, ios, mobile

I have both android and ios apps on the market. Minimum SDK of Android is API level 8 and base deployment of ios app is 5.0. I would like to increase the min android version to 15 and base deployment of ios app to 7.0. My question is how the current android users who use os version lower than 15 are affected? Or how the current ios users who use os version lower than 7.0 are affected? Can they see my app on the to-be-updated list of apple and google play store? If they see that what happens when they click on update button? If the button does not work, are they always going to see my app on to-be-updated list of the stores? Can they still use my app with old version after the update is released?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should have two releases: one for the old Androids and one for the new Androids. In the latter you set the min SDK. The installer would check the SDK and choose the correct app to be installed.